# How to check if an element has a specific child?

Tags: javascript

How to check if an element has a specific child?

I added children to my element using:

```
var child1 = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(child1);
```

How can I check whether `child1` is already attached to `body`?

```
if (document.body.alreadyHas(child1)) …
                  ^^^^^^^^^^
                what to do here?
```

Comment: So at least tell us for what you are looking

Comment: What "specific child"? Do you have a DOM element to test? Or a class name? Or an id? Or a string which may occur somewhere within a child?

Comment: @deceze all children I added are DOMs

Comment: So you want to test whether a DOM element `child1` is already attached to `element`...?

Comment: Yes, that is it @deceze

Comment: You should [edit] your question to clarify that, answerers are already confused.

Comment: BTW, `appendChildren` doesn't actually exist…!?

Comment: @deceze thank you very much for the edit, i fixed the typo you mentioned (appendChildren)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given references to two elements, you can test if one is the child of the other by using the [`.parentElement` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement) as follows:

```
if (child1.parentElement === parent1) {
  // do something
}
```

So in your specific case where you've said the parent is the `body`, you can do this:

```js
    var child1 = document.createElement('div');
    var child2 = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(child1); // note we only append one

    if (child1.parentElement === document.body) {
      console.log("child1 is a child of the body"); // this will run
    }
    if (child2.parentElement === document.body) {
      console.log("child2 is a child of the body"); // this won't run
    }
```

Comment: Finally I got something that works and simple to understand !! Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using HTML DOM `querySelector()` Method .

```
if(document.querySelector("div .example").length>0)
{
//your code
}
```

Comment: No, that tests whether an element has any descendents matching that selector, it doesn't test for a specific element.

Comment: @nnnnnn But the "specific element" can actually be a selector (it is not clear in the question)

Comment: If you want to check a div which has `id="example"` you can use `document.querySelector("div#example").length>0`) it will work I think .

Answer (score 2):

### You can use Node.contains()

you can find more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains)

```
const child1 = document.createElement('div');

document.body.appendChild(child1);

if(document.contains(child1)){
 //your code
}
```

#### A quick note about document.querySelector

This answer that was posted earlier will throw an error in case the element doesn't exist, I wouldn't use it:

```
if(document.querySelector("div .example").length>0)
{
//your code
}
```

You can open your console in this page and test it:

> VM113:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')
> at :1:39

If you want to use document.querySelector use this instead, it will return null if doesn't find any matches:

```
if(document.querySelector("div .example")){
// returns null if it div doesn't exist inside DOM
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
<div id="myDiv">
  <p>tag p</p>
  <strong>tag strong</strong>
  <h5>title h5</h5>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click here</button>
</html>

<script>

function myFunction(){
  if(jQuery("#myDiv").children("h5").length > 0){
      console.log("Found!");
  }else{
    console.log("Not Found!");
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Is important you count the amount of children found, with length > 0 because if you don't count, the code will be true anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure element is direct child of a node, `querySelector` and `Node.contains` methods are wasteful because they will look into descendents also. Basically you will be searching the whole DOM tree, not only the direct children.

More performant alternative is, if you are going to look into elements only:

```
Array.from(parent.children).some(el => el === target);
```

If you want to check text nodes and everything:

```
Array.from(parent.childNodes).some(el => el === target);
```

The `some` methods shortcuts and returns immediately when a matching child is found.